# regular expression to validate digit range

Tags: javascript

I've written the following regular expression to validate digits between 1 and 99999 inclusive, however, it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
var validate = /^[1-9]{1}$^[0-9]{0-4}$|^9999$/
```

Comment: You're trying to match lines that contain an end-of-line (and a start) in their middle. It's impossible. I.e., drop the `$^` in the middle of your regexp. Also, the syntax for repetition ranges is `{0,4}`.

Comment: `if numb > 0 && numb < 10000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
var validate = /^[1-9][0-9]{0,4}$/
```

It'll match strings that consist only of 1-5 digits, and do not begin with zero.